# ¿Existe alguna forma de resumir los if - else if en esta función?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un código javascript que muestra la caratula del álbum y la letra (lyric) de la canción que está sonando en una radio online.

Uso 2 APIs diferentes para obtener cada dato, para la caratula del álbum uso Itunes y para las lyrics Vagalume.

El asunto que ambas APIs usan diferentes criterios para el nombre del artista y la canción cuando son más de un autor, como el criterio no es siempre el mismo, comencé por hacer una lista de excepciones, cambiando el nombre del artista y el nombre de la canción de forma personalizada.

Al cabo de unos días la lista de excepciones comenzó a crecer, yo pensé que se trataría de pocas canciones, pero ahora veo que son muchas y los `IF ELSE IF` comenzaron a crecer.

No se si existe alguna forma de resumirlos ya que como les comenté el criterio usado por la API de Vagalume no es siempre el mismo.

De todos modos les comparto un resumen de una función para ver si alguien puede ver algo que yo no veo para evitar esta extensa repetición de comparaciones.

```
this.refreshLyric = (currentSong, currentArtist) => {
        var vagalume_api = 'https://api.vagalume.com.br/search.php?';
      
        //Remove contributing artists separated by commas, slash or &
        var currentCleanArtist = cleanText(currentArtist);
        
        //mi lista de canciones personalizadas para Vagalume
        if (currentSong == 'Walk Away' && currentArtist == 'Alle Farben & James Blunt') {
          currentSong = 'Walk Away (Feat. James Blunt)';
          currentCleanArtist = 'Alle Farben & James Blunt';
        } else if (currentSong == 'On My Way' && currentArtist == 'Alan Walker, Sabrina Carpenter & Farruko') {
          currentSong = 'On My Way (With Sabrina Carpenter & Farruko)';
          currentCleanArtist = 'Alan Walker';
          } else if (currentArtist == 'Years & Years') {
          currentCleanArtist = 'Years & Years';
          } else if (currentSong == 'The Fix' && currentArtist == 'Nelly feat. Jeremih') {
          currentSong = 'The Fix (Feat. Jeremih)';
          currentCleanArtist = 'Nelly';
          } else if (currentSong == 'La Lá'  && currentArtist == 'Mike Bahía,Ovy On The Drums') {
          currentSong = 'La Lá (Feat. Ovy On The Drums)';
          currentCleanArtist = 'Mike Bahía';
          } else if (currentSong == 'Stay Homa'  && currentArtist == 'Stay Homas / Sr. Wilson') {
          currentSong = 'Stay Homa (Feat. Sr. Wilson)';
          currentCleanArtist = 'Stay Homas';
          } else if (currentSong == 'Love Games' && currentArtist == 'Alex Parker & Olivia Addams') {
          currentSong = 'Love Games';
          currentCleanArtist = 'Alex Parker';
          } else if (currentSong == '+' && currentArtist == 'Aitana / Cali y El Dandee') {
          currentSong = '+ (Feat. Cali y El Dandee)';
          currentCleanArtist = 'Aitana';
          } else if (currentSong == 'Play' && currentArtist == 'K391 / Alan Walker / Tungevaag & Mangoo') {
          currentSong = 'Play (With K-391, Martin Tungevaag, Feat. Mangoo)';
          currentCleanArtist = 'Alan Walker';
          } else if (currentSong == 'La Petita Rambla del Poble (feat. Txarango) [XL]' && currentArtist == 'Cesk Freixas') {
          currentSong = 'La Petita Rambla del Poble Sec (feat. Txarango) [XL]';
          currentCleanArtist = 'Cesk Freixas';
          } else if (currentSong == 'Where Are Ü Now LIVE (with Justin Bieber)' && currentArtist == 'Skrillex & Diplo') {
          currentSong = 'Where Are U Now (feat. Justin Bieber)';
          currentCleanArtist = 'Skrillex';
          } else if (currentSong == "Don't You Need Somebody" && currentArtist == 'RedOne feat. Enrique Iglesias, R. City, Serayah & Shaggy') {
          currentSong = "Don't You Need Somebody";
          currentCleanArtist = 'RedOne';
          } else if (currentSong == 'Flashbacks' && currentArtist == 'Sonny Fodera & Sonickraft') {
          currentSong = 'Flashbacks (Feat. Sonickraft)';
          currentCleanArtist = 'Sonny Fodera';
          } 
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
          if (this.status === 200) {
             var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                    if (data.type === 'exact' || data.type === 'aprox') {
                        var lyric = normalizeText(data, currentCleanArtist);
                                            
                        document.getElementById('lyric').innerHTML = lyric.replace(/\n/g, '<br />'); 
                        
                    } else {
                    //more stuff
                    //
                    //
                    //
                    }
            } else {
                   var page = new Page();
                    page.refreshLyric2(currentSong, currentCleanArtist);
                   }
            }
        }
            xhttp.open('GET', vagalume_api + '&apikey=' + API_KEY + '&art=' + urlencode(currentCleanArtist) + '&mus=' + urlencode(currentSong.toLowerCase()), true);
            xhttp.send()
}
```

Comment: Porque utilizas una API diferente para obtener las carátulas? Según la [documentación](https://api.vagalume.com.br/docs/discografia/), puedes acceder también a las carátulas de las canciones

Comment: Por que la API de Itunes tiene el 99% de las caratulas, son verificadas por el equipo de Apple y son de excelente calidad, Vagalume tiene muy pocas en comparación.. Musixmatch usa los mismos criterios que Itunes pero esta API no es gratuita,  solo muestra el 30% de las letras. Me vi obligado hacer este mix para poder obtener la caratula + lyrics.

Comment: Veo un poco complejo realizar algún tipo de match entre dos APIS con distintas respuestas al hacer una petición. Lo que podrías hacer es tomar el artista y realizar una búsqueda por artista primero con un `filter`, y una vez obtenido el resultado, realizar un `find` combinado con algun `includes` que contenga una palabra de la canción. De todas formas, esperaría a ver si algún colega tiene una solución mejor

Comment: Yo también lo veo muy complejo, de todos modos cada API tiene su función separada, no se envían los mismos `GET`. Si el criterio de Vagalume fuera siempre el mismo se podría solucionar con una función que cambiara el orden en el artista y el nombre de la canción. Pero he visto otras canciones en las que Vagalume no usa Feat, sino With y otras usa &. El código queda feo de ver pero funciona y la respuesta es rápida. Solo que no me gusta verlo jajaja

Comment: Lo que pasa es que el margen de error al realizar filtros con string es demasiado, porque una palabra que cambie alterará toda la respuesta; por último si te ves obligado a hacerlo, realiza filtros con string de una palabra, no una frase completa porque el margen negativo sería demasiado.

Comment: Tienes razón, creo que el remedio puede ser peor que la enfermedad. Lo dejaré así mientras funcione bien y rápido.

Answer (score 1):

Por un lado se me ocurre que podrías agrupar en una estructura los datos y recorrerla buscando coincidencias. De ese modo, si te aparecen más excepciones, sólo tendrías que modificar la estructura (un documento JSON, por ejemplo):

```
const DATOS= [
  {
    currentSong: 'Walk Away',
    currentArtist:'Alle Farben & James Blunt',
    currentCleanSong = 'Walk Away (Feat. James Blunt)';
    currentCleanArtist = 'Alle Farben & James Blunt';
    
  },
  {
    currentSong: 'On My Way',
    currentArtist:'Alan Walker, Sabrina Carpenter & Farruko',
    currentCleanSong = 'On My Way (With Sabrina Carpenter & Farruko)';
    currentCleanArtist = 'Alan Walker';
  }
];

function normalize(song, artist) {
  let clean = DATA.find(elem => elem.currentSong === song && elem.currentArtist ===artist);
  if (clean) {
    return [clean.currentCleanSong, clean.currentCleanArtist]
  } else {
    return [song,artist];
}
```

Por otro lado, me pregunto si no intentas hilar demasiado fino: La mayoría de las búsquedas deberían funcionar con parámetros más generales: prueba a buscas uno de los artistas y el título de la canción, y luego en los resultados intenta comprobar si en los datos están los otros artistas en el título o en la lista de artistas, por ejemplo.

Comment: +10 por tu esfuerzo, pero no te preocupes, lo dejaré así, los criterios de Vagalume son muy cambiantes (no hay un criterio fijo). Acabo de agregar una nueva excepción y esta vez es muy distinta, no tiene solución con código esto.  `else if (currentSong == 'Juju On That Beat' && currentArtist == 'Zay Hilfigerrr And Zayion McCall') {
    currentSong = 'Juju On That Beat (TZ Anthem) (Feat. Zayion McCall)';
    currentCleanArtist = 'Zay Hilfigerrr';`
    }